# Docusign Embedded Signing , How can sender share the “recipient signing URL” with multiple signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I am building a customer web portal or a self-service platform, one of the features of the portal is for customer to upload required documents. Customer would have to go through full authentication to access the  web portal to upload required documents and perform other functions.
I want to embed DocuSign and use its signature capabilities for customer to fill out forms and provide signatures. Some of the documents requires multiple signatures from legal parties of an organization.
My questions:

1. How do I send DocuSign to multiple signers?
2. Would each signer have to authenticate to the portal to sign documents or is there a way DocuSign can route document to the signers without all of them authenticating to the portal?

Answer (score 0):

Each signers/recipient can have their own unique URL which is different based on the recipient involved.
You can have multiple recipients sign the same document/envelope and each of time can sign, either in turn, or whenever based on the routing order.
URLs for signing should not be shared, as they are private for the signer.
Your app can either embed the URL inside, or if you would rather use remote signing, then each recipient would get an email with the link to sign.

There's no need for signers to authenticate, unless you wish them to do so, which is certainly more secure, but not a requirement of DocuSign.

[Here is a code example for embedded signing in 7 languages.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded)

[Here is a code example for remote signing in 7 languages.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote)